# How can I hide the navigation bar when pushing a view controller?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I'm making customized UIScrollView such like pinterest's two column view.

The scrollview should have search function. So I tried to use UISearchDisplayController but I can't because UISearchDisplayController implements only UITableView.

So, I created  search display controller such like UISearchDisplayController. It's good. well done.

But I have a big problem. I can't implement completely behavior of UISearchDisplayController when go to detail view.

See below images.

this image is UISearchDisplayController's behavior on Simulator's Contact App.

[image]

Detail view have a navigationBar when pushed. but first view's navigationBar is hidden.

[image]

The UISearchDisplayController's behavior is good to transition view. Search view don't have UINavigationBar and detail view has UINavigationBar separately. but my controller can't do that.

I call `setNavigationBarHidden:animated` method try to hide navigation bar when touch UISearchBar on search view.

How to implement second image. any ideas?

sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: do you want to hide second view's bar hide when u pushed that view?

Comment: Why do you assume the first views navigation bar is hidden just because it has a different tint and theres a search field on it?

Comment: try this code it may solve your issue [self.navigationController hidesBottomBarWhenPushed]

Comment: What is the problem with setNavigationBarHidden:animated? Is it not hiding? If that is the case, why cant you add your searchbar to navigation bar itself by removing backbarbutton? It should behave the same way right?

Comment: @SmartWork `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` is just hide bottom bar such as UITabBar.

Comment: I want to implement totally same behavior of UISearchDisplayController include view-transition. Did you tried Mail, SMS, Contacts's search function?

Answer (score 0):

The search bar is different view, so here you need to call the below methods while view is navigating from one view to others.

```
self.navController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

or

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
```